# array sort method doesn't work outside cypress each but works inside

Tags: javascript, sorting, cypress

Here is the program piece where you can see that:

1. var likes = [] is defined before cy.get:
2. likes is populated inside the each () method
   I want to sort likes array as in the below code. But that is not getting sorted.
   cy is cypress
   The problem is that I like to sort this likes array outside cy.get(..).each() as next instruction not inside. But that is not working and I have no clue as to why. Please could you help in here ?

```js
    var likes = []
    
    cy.get('.blogs').each(($el, index) => {
        const bcy = cy.wrap($el)
        bcy.get('#viewBlog').click()
        const like =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        likes[index] = like
        for(let i=like;i--; )
          bcy.get('.blogsDetail').eq(index).contains('likes').click()
        
      })

     likes.sort((a, b) => b - a)  //Sorting at this place doesn't work
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of your code. What is your goal?

Comment: logic is to define an array, then populate it inside cy.get.each function and then to sort that array outside that function as a next instruction. I edited the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress commands are asynchronous. To sort the array after the `each` command, you have to use a `then` callback:

```js
var likes = []
  cy.get('.blogs').each(($el, index) => {
    const bcy = cy.wrap($el)
    bcy.get('#viewBlog').click()
    const like =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    likes[index] = like
    for(let i=like;i--; )
      bcy.get('.blogsDetail').eq(index).contains('likes').click()
  }).then(() => {
    likes.sort((a, b) => b - a)
  })
```

Wheny you call the `sort` method out of a `then`, it's executed before any cypress command and you have an empty array at that moment. See it in debugger:[image]

Comment: Mikhail Bolotov, I edited my question to be more clear. Could you have a look and please explain ?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks ! It was really hard to see that for me that the cypress get each call is a promise . Wish there was a. Async await for cypress too